# Rewriting MFC functions use C++ standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm writing a Windows service (to operate a binary file) use C++ standard library in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to re-write some functions are developed in MFC. I have a question that how can I rewrite (or use another instead) class `CObject` that used in the MFC application.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? MFC works perfectly with ATL, STL COM and every mixed environment...

Comment: @xMRi  MFC does not work inside a Windows Service.

Comment: Sure it does. One of the most famous frameworks for services from PJ Naughter was first designed to work with MFC. I have at least four services that contain a bunch of MFC code!

Comment: I've saw in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163905/using-mfc-in-windows-service) that maybe it's difficult to use MFC in windows service. And as I know MFC is an old and death technology so I want to rewrite my funtions using standard library or maybe ATL.

Comment: Today MFC is still not a death technology: See [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/27/happy-25th-birthday-mfc/)